The right harmonica to use
I play heavy guitar.drop c and am looking to mix it up with harmonica parts.
I'm just wondering what would be the best key for harmonica to use.

Depends on the key of the song, not the tuning of the guitar.

You need to tell us what kind of music you want to play. Also, do you want to play chords, sort of Bob Dylan-style, or do you want to learn to play licks? You will likely end up wanting more than one harmonica, and there's more possible choices than just choosing a key.

The chosen key for any harp in any song is purely dependent on the key of the song, not the guitar tuning. Vtc.

First off: In many genres, including rock, Harmonicas are mostly not played in the key they are labelled in, but in the dominant key. This is called second position. You can use the circle of fifths (... F > C > G > D > A > E > B > F# ...) and remember the harp (as we sometimes call harmonicas) is typically played one step to the right of its labelled key. To play in F# you use a harp labelled as B, and so on.
While the you can pick up a standard tuned harmonica anywhere, you can get more out of the instrument faster, by using another tuning. As a guitar player using an alternate tuning, you know just changing the tuning a little bit can make a lot of difference. A player called Will Wilde plays heavy rock licks using his own tuning, which i turn is an adaptation of Brendan Power's Powerbender harmonicas.
Since you tagged the question electric guitar and you play drop C, I'm going to assume you play some sort of rock, or a similar style.
I'm no authority on rock harmonica, but Will Wilde is. I quote an FAQ page of his:

WHAT IS THE BEST KEY FOR PLAYING ROCK?
It all depends on the song. Rock songs come in ALL keys, the key of
the song is usually determined by the singer's range.  However, the
most common keys found in rock music are, E, A, G and D, so you would
use A,D,C and G harps to play in second position.

This advice applies no matter if you go with a standard tuned harmonica, Wilde tuning or Powerbender.
I would recommend you to try one of the tunings I mentioned, you can check out what they can do here
Wilde tuning:

https://www.wildetuning.com/about (The quote above is from the FAQ at
this page) https://www.seydel1847.de/rockharmonica (plenty of clips
advertising the tuning)

Powerbender:

https://www.brendan-power.com/harmonicas-10hole.php#power-bender
(general info and models for sale)
https://www.brendan-power.com/lucky13-powerbender.php

Comparing the two, the Wilde tuning is a bit more specialised. It has more of the chords, but requires harder bends if you want to play licks. The Powerbender has more notes available right away, and might be more versitile if you want to play in more different keys.
Also, you can find the Powerbenders in cheaper harmonicas, which might be nice if you just want to try it out. They are also available as 13-hole harps, with an extra base octave built in at the bottom. The Wilde tuning is pretty much only available from Seydel. They make good harmonicas (I often play them myself), but not as cheap.
If you don't like the sound of these tunings, or just want to pick something up at any music store, go with a standard tuned harp in one of the keys mentioned above.

Tom Morello has said that F# is “the key of rock” and I have to agree, but E is a close second.

@ToddWilcox - what reasons does Tom have for this? I can't ever remember playing rock songs in F#! E, A and sometimes D, yes.

@Tim Exhibit A is definitely “Immigrant Song”. Exhibit B is a self referential but it’s “Bulls On Parade”. Also “Know Your Enemy”.

@ToddWilcox - I listened to Immigrant - Led Zep, G, Nirvana F, but that may well have been the band tuning. I see the reason F#(m) is favoured is to incorporate the rock chords of A and E for starters. Tried to listen to the others, but really couldn't cope! Sorry!

@Tim If you concluded that the original Led Zeppelin "Immigrant Song" is not in F# minor then I'm afraid your guitar is out of tune. But my main point is that a harmonica player who wants to rock and especially one with a guitar in dropped C probably will not be satisfied with keys that are often played with cowboy chords. The most common keys that I've found in drop tunings are the minor keys of the lowest note (C in this case), and then two and four frets up (D and E). In the more common dropped D tuning, that's D, E, and F#. This asker probably would prefer cross harp playing also.

@ToddWilcox - that puts my piano, the guitar and a tuner all out of tune!!!

@ToddWilcox - as far as Know Your Enemy, it's poorly tuned guitars in between G and F#, but I'll give you that one!

@Tim This conversation is inappropriate here but you have something going on in your key determination process. A huge array of sources confirms immigrant song is in F# minor. If you find good video of Page playing it, the opening riff is clearly based on the second fret of the E string. Wikipedia and every transcription I’ve been able to find agree. As does Tom Morello, who might be the best living electric guitarist.

@ToddWilcox - as stated earlier, it may well be the not-quite-in-concert pitch of tuning that's the problem. If a guitar is tuned down, but still playing an F# shaped chord, is that still F#? Debatable, maybe not here. After many years in house bands, can't see (hear?) my pitch recognition is off at all. And I'm the best living electric guitarist - it's just that no-one has ever heard of me... End of discussion!
